# No console output in R

Tags: r

I'm using a script that contains some `tryCatch`-commands and creats a PNG-plot. When I run this script and an error occurs, the error handler works fine (including printing the error). But afterwards I can't print anything in the console, even `print("text")` does not show any results. However, error messages are still shown (e.g., printing `geewd()` results in the error message `Error: Could not find function "geewd"`). Any idea what's the problem?

(Because of the complexity of the script, unfortunately, I can't provide a MWE.)

Comment: How about trying to reproduce the issue with less code?

Comment: @Яaffael I can't find a reproducible example as it doesn't seem to be a `tryCatch`-error (normal `tryCatch` examples work fine, including those containing plotting), so I don't have any idea where the error might be located.

Comment: Realistically it is impossible to solve an error which cannot be reproduced :/

Comment: @Яaffael I'm sure it would be reproducible if I would know what's the problem. :-) I'm puzzled by what could lead to suppressed "normal" console printing while error messages are still printed. So I thought maybe someone has already encountered this problem.

Comment: Try    sink(NULL)   to plug an open sink

Comment: @mdsumner You're right, typing `sink(NULL)` helps. I did have a `sink(NULL)` within the error handler, but it was not executed because the error occurred within the error handler before the `sink(NULL)` command. Adding `sink(NULL)` to the `finally`-handler solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your help! If you write your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see this problem when a `sink()` has been opened but not closed, probably because an error occurred before the closing code was reached.

Try this to plug an open sink:

```
sink(NULL)
```